# slow mysql query with left outer join and OR clause

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM video LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (video.id = comments.video_id)
WHERE comments.posted_by_user = 1234 OR video.id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I have indices on `video.id` `comments.posted_by_user` and `comments.video_id`. However, mysql does a full table scan on the video table which is taking a lot of time. Using a `UNION` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` makes it faster but not an option since the query is generated by the django ORM.

Why is the combination of `OR` clause and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` preventing mysql from using an index and how can I prevent it ?